# Error creating a project on Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have upgraded Android Studio from 2.2 to 2.3 and when I create a new Android project with a navigation activity I got two errors:

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:   
java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
```

When I had the older version I solved the problem changing the value of buildToolsVersion in build.gradle file to 23.0.3 instead of 25.0.0.

In the new version I make the same change and I got the following error:

```
Gradle Sync Issues
Error:Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project 
':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
Update Build Tools version and sync project
```

But this is not the one change I make. I also must change the version of android support libraries on the dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

These errors appear on Debian Linux. I have a colleague that works on Windows and he can create new projects using Android Studio 2.3 version.

How can I fix those errors?

Thanks.

Comment: Share  your gradle file. Because y.our build tool < 25.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `File->Project Structure...` (or press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S`).

In the left sidebar, click `Project` (under `SDK Location`), and change `Gradle version` (to something like `3.2`) and change `Android Plugin Version` (to something like `2.2.0` or `2.2.2`).

This will rollback your AndroidStudio to before the `2.3` upgrade so you can continue to develop until Google gets around to fixing whatever's wrong with `2.3`. Then you can also change your buildToolsVersion to `23.0.3` to avoid getting the

```
Error:Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':app'
```

error, and your project should compile properly again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is what I did. I configured projects as following: Gradle version: 2.14.1, android plugin version: 2.2.3 and buildToolsVersion 23.0.3. If I use 3.2 for Gradle version it also works.

Comment: you are the legend!

Answer (score -1):

In you gradle, build tool must be >=25

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25'
```

And you change support to 25.2.0 (now is  the newest)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

upload Android SDK Build Tools version 25.0.1 in android Studio 2.3
Project Structure -> Properties -> Build Tools version 25.0.1

After doing this project gets build without any error.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I changed the Properties as you mentioned but I can't build the apk due to the two first errors mentioned above about AAPT process. I am stuck.

Answer (score -2):

This issue was happening on my phone which is a Xiaomi Phones running on Miui 8. After turning off Miui Optimizations on Developer Settings, restarting the phone a recompiling the application it worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636693/2885194

Comment: I can't create the apk file because I have errors in the project.