# Error Building project on android studio 2.2 ubuntu 32 bit os

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have this problem building my project ever since i  upgraded the minSdkVersion to 15 and buildToolsVersion to 25.0.3 i keep having this error 
 **Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands**

i have tried downgrading the build tool to 24 but i get this error
 **25.0.0 is the minimum required to build**

Comment: follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625804/error-creating-a-project-on-android-studio-2-3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916513/gradle-build-exception-aapt-process-not-ready-to-receive-commands)

Comment: please paste your build.gradle here

Comment: thanks @Nilesh Rathod  i followed the instructions from the answer in the fisrt link and that solved it

Comment: most welcome@chuksleomc